# scrollIntoView functionality broken after loading changing navigation (router-link)

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3, ionic6, js-scrollintoview

I have this little Ionic 6 Vue app which has two menu's - left and right.

```
    <IonSplitPane content-id="main-content">
      <ion-menu menuId="left-menu" side="start" content-id="main-content" type="push">
        <ion-content>
          <ion-menu-toggle menu="right-menu" autoHide="false">
            ...
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-menu>
      <ion-menu menuId="right-menu" side="end" contentId="main-content" type="overlay" :disabled="!bookHasChildren">
        <ion-content>
          <ion-menu-toggle menu="right-menu" autoHide="false">
            ... 
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-menu>
      <ion-router-outlet id="main-content" ref="ionRouter"></ion-router-outlet>
    </IonSplitPane>
```

When selecting a book, the right menu lists sub-chapter-links. Scrolling to those sub-chapters in the main view is implemented with the `[scrollIntoView][1]` method.

```
function scrollToElement() {
  try {
    const elementToScrollTo = divs.value.find((element) => element.localName == scrollStore.scrollElementMain);
    if (elementToScrollTo != undefined && elementToScrollTo != elementToScrollTo.offsetTop) {
      // scrolling
      elementToScrollTo.scrollIntoView();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // logging scrolling error
  }
}
```

This works fine until user clicks on left menu links where another books is loaded.
No error logging, the scrollIntoView-functionality just doesn't work anymore.

I am not sure why this breaks the scrollIntoView functionality.

Have tried so many other options and approaches, but without any success.

**Demo**:
[image]

**Code**
is on [GitHub](https://github.com/mamitry/ionic6-mybook)

PS:  Cannot show in `code sandbox` as I am using Vue with `script setup` and I couldn't find a free code sandbox which supports this.

Comment: You can try stackblitz.com. It supports script setup

Comment: @Duannx I have tried stackblitz.com, but it's not running. All imports of custom components are logged with warnings "Failed to resolve component"